# mkdir() is not creating a new directory

Tags: java, file, android-studio, mkdir, mkdirs

I have included

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and I want to save image.

But before that I wanted to check that is it creating directory or not and it is not. I am using File Explorer to check that is it creating or not and it is even not showing me my app package folder.

```
package com.example.parth.project2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button; 
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;

public class saveData extends AppCompatActivity {
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_save_data);

       ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagesave);
       Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Savepic);


       button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
               File fileBase = new File(filepath, "Test");
               if (!fileBase.exists()) {
                   fileBase.mkdirs();
                   Toast.makeText(saveData.this, fileBase.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
           }
       });

   }

}
```

Comment: What api level are you targeting?

Comment: API 26: Android 8.0 (Oreo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

```
String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

//or

String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

Instead of :

```
String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try to create a file like this?

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "MyFile.txt");
file.createNewFile();
```

Comment: Ohh damm (facepalm), my bad.

Answer (score -1):

Try :

```
fileBase.mkdir();
```

Instead of :

```
fileBase.mkdirs();
```